# Allocation of a struct vector containing an array

Tags: c++

Imagine a structure

```cpp
struct A {
    int i;
    int arr[1000];
};

std::vector<A> vec;
```

I cannot find an answer to know if the array "arr" in my structure "A" will take up space on the stack or not at all.
I these although the vector will allocate an array of "A" which will be on the heap and will not impact my stack but will my "arr" array impact my stack?

```cpp
std::vector <A> vec1 (1000000);

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vec2 (1000000);
```

Will vec1 "destroy" my stack and better to use vec2?

**Edit for the comment.**

Why can vec1 allocate more elements than vec2?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    int i;
    int arr[1000];
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vec1;
  std::vector<A> vec2;
  std::cout << vec1.max_size() << '\n' << vec2.max_size() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<A>` allocates it's backing storage on the heap so all the `A`s in the `std::vector` will be on the heap.  The stack size (`sizeof`) of any `std::vector<T>` is usually the same as the size of 2 pointers (implementation dependent).

Comment: The vector will be on the stack, but the data in the vector will be allocated on the heap. But I suppose that an implementation of std::vector might allocate data on the stack for small vector sizes, but I'm not sure if this is covered by the standard.

Comment: For the update look at `sizeof(std::unique_ptr<A>)` vs `sizeof(A)` - a vector is a container of "things" if the things are different sizes then you can hold more or less things in the total potentially available space.  Also note the number of potential elements are stupidly large in both cases (64-bit).

Comment: I had no measure like this, thank you!

Comment: `vector::max_size` isn't meaningful when you are targeting a 64-bit platform. It represents filling the whole address space with elements of the vector, and you can't buy one system with that much RAM.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Small buffer optimization is not possible for `std::vector` (in contrast to short string optimization for `std::string`, which is possible). There are some restrictions in the standard that disallows it. For instance, IIRC, swapping contents of two vectors may not invalidate iterators/pointer/references to their elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I understood correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` is one of [AllocatorAwareContainers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer) and default allocator use dynamic allocation (often called heap allocation, which is true for systems with heap-like memory model).

When using those two

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vec1;
std::vector<A> vec2;
```

both have own advantages and disadvantages. The `vec1` offers arguably better time of resizing container itself because unique_ptr is quite small. `vec2` offers instances of A with adjacent storage but resize time would be higher because of move operation used on each element. `vec1` allocates only storage for pointers and not for the object itselves, by reaching that number you likely won't have memory left to create instances of `A`.

For lesser automatic storage (stack) footprint when using vec2 you might want to avoid creation of `A` temporary at all and use `emplace_XXX` methods to create instances of A right in vector's storage.

Comment: Thanks but if everything is on the heap, why can vec1 have more elements than vec2? (see my edit)

Comment: @antho size of elements. maximum storage (in bytes) would be same. But that maximum size is usually comparable to maximum memory available to your program, so there is no deal, unless you're using some oddball implementation, where maximum size of vector is smaller.

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson Objects are not allocated. Their storage is allocated and objects are then initialized (constructed) there.

Comment: @Martin.Martinsson By allocation, I mean reserving a memory space for object storage (which may be on the heap, on the stack, in the data segment, etc.). Especially with `std::vector`, it is important to distinguish between allocation and initialization, since they are generally not performed at the same time (for instance, `reserve` allocates storage, `push_back` then initializes a new element). BTW, you may want to learn the difference between new-operator and new-expression. New-operator does not call any constructor.